# Declaring a variable inside an if block in c++

Tags: c++, scope

I am new to c++ and often I find myself wanting to declare a variable type depending on some external input, such as command line input or reading from a text file.

For example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   if (argv[1] == "thing1") {
       Thing1 thing;
   } else if (argv[1] == "thing2") {
       Thing2 thing;
   }

// More code
}
```

This does not work, because I cannot use the variable thing outside of the if block, so my question is how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Are Thing1 and Thing2 compatible?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are looking to do some run-time polymorphism.  In C++ you can't really do polymorphism with stack objects -- the closest you can come is to fake it, by declaring both objects on the stack at the outer scope, and then only using one of them, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   Thing1 thing1;
   Thing2 thing2;
   bool useThing1 = true;

   if (strcmp(argv[1], "thing1") == 0) {
      useThing1 = true;
   } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "thing2") == 0) {
      useThing1 = false;
   }

   if (useThing1)
   {
      thing1.DoSomething();
   }
   else
   {
      thing2.DoSomething();
   }

   [... rest of code ...]
}
```

... but that isn't very satisfying, and won't scale up well if you need more than two types of `Thing`.

A better approach is to use inheritance and dynamic allocation, like this:

```
class ThingBase
{
public:
   ThingBase() {}
   virtual ~ThingBase() {}

   virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Thing1 : public ThingBase
{
public:
   Thing1() {}

   virtual void DoSomething() {std::cout << "Thing1::DoSomething() called" << std::endl;}
};

class Thing2 : public ThingBase
{
public:
   Thing2() {}

   virtual void DoSomething() {std::cout << "Thing2::DoSomething() called" << std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   ThingBase * thing = NULL;

   if (strcmp(argv[1], "thing1") == 0) {
       thing = new Thing1;
   } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "thing2") == 0) {
       thing = new Thing2;
   }

   if (thing)
   {
      thing->DoSomething();

      [... rest of code ...]

      delete thing;
   }
}
```

... this way is better because the `[... rest of code..]` section of `main()` doesn't have to know (or care) about what subclass of `ThingBase` it is working with; in particular, it can just call the `DoSomething()` method on its `thing` pointer and the appropriate method implementation will automatically be called.  That helps keep the calling code simple (which gets more important as you start adding more types of `Thing`)

Comment: Shoudn't it be using `std::unique_ptr` instead of naked new?

Comment: Sure, that would be a very good way to avoid any chance of a memory leak -- but in order to avoid complicating the example code with additional concepts, I'll leave it as-is for now.

Comment: You forgot about std::variant

Comment: I agree with @JeremyFriesner's view - too often, an answer to one question introduces 5 extra concepts that the asker hasn't learned about yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Thing1` and `Thing2` are different classes you'll need differently typed `thing` variables. The best option is to move 'more code' into functions and call these for `Thing1` or `Thing2` from inside your block.

Answer (score 0):

like java reflect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        printf("CalssBase\n");
    }
};


class A : public Base {
public: 
    A() {
        printf("CalssA\n");
    }
};


class REG_A {
public:
    static Base* newInst() {
        return new A();
    }
};

Base* p;

#define CREATE(name) \
p = REG_##name::newInst();

int main(void) {
    CREATE(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how do you make it change depending on argv[1]?